# What might select a field and scroll to it, without using 'scroll', 'focus', etc?

Tags: html, javascript, looking-for-a-script

I have inherited maintenance of a mess of a project. There's a particular set of (rather tall) pages that scroll way down the page on every page load, and eventually it occurred to me that it's because a particular field is in focus after the page is loaded, and this field (of course?) was scrolled into view.

The thing is, nowhere (relevant) in the entire code base can I find the (partial) words `scroll`, `focus`, `select`, or `activat`, so I really can't figure out WHY this one field is given focus!

Setting `autofocus` on the first form field does not change the behaviour (although this may possibly be due to timing of scripts). I can use `window.onload` with `myFirstInputElement.focus()`, but this scrolls that field to the top of the view, and still does not show the top of the page. Trying to use `.scrollTo()` or `.scrollTop()` has no effect.

What else might I be overlooking?

Alas, this is incredibly complicated code, with template generators and whatnot, so it is not possible to show you a condensed, minimal example exhibiting this behaviour (if I could, I could probably spot the problem myself).

Comment: Does your site use third party JavaScript?  It could be something outside of the code base that is still used in the page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, as far as I can see we only use locally stored scripts, including a local version of jQuery (v1.02).

Comment: try to inspect jQuery plugins, if any. Try to inspect all javascipts, which come with template generator. Try to inspect page loading commenting javascripts out one by one.